# Are there any unintended side effects of limiting a mongodb docker container's CPU or RAM?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, aws, docker

It's easy to limit RAM and CPU usage for a docker container with the `docker update -m` [command.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/)

We have limited RAM and CPU using `docker update` on multiple docker mongodb containers, particularly on an AWS ubuntu 18.04 EC2 instance. We are running into issues where the server becomes inactive, and we believe the culprit is ambiguous RAM consumption.

Since AWS doesn't have RAM usage metrics by default, we installed `atop` to monitor resource usage. My
question [here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314815/how-is-bind-ip-all-usage-from-mongodb-docker-containers-related-to-cpu-ram?noredirect=1#comment613606_314815) has some example output when the server was inactive.

*Are there any unintended side effects of limiting a mongodb's RAM or CPU limit with `docker update`?*

Comment: What is the `docker update -m` command that you used? In general you do not want to limit the amount of memory available to a database server e.g. provide as much memory as possible. If you do limit the memory, make sure that you have adequately tested that configuration with the load issued to the database.

Comment: the link to the command is in the first sentence ```-m``` is for memory

Comment: What is the exact command with arguments that you used?

Comment: i do not have a record of the exact command with arguments. we limited the memory to one for example to a max of 4GiB of memory (out of 16GB) and 30% of total CPU of the machine. ```docker stats``` confirm both of these